# Move a webbrowser during runtime in Windows form,C#

Tags: winforms, dynamic, runtime, webbrowser-control, move

I'm currently working with a webbrowser control in winforms, I just want to drag and move this webbrowser to any place in the form during runtime. Is it possible? if so please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an example on CodeProject that works really well.

[Move controls on a form at runtime](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31840/Move-controls-on-a-form-at-runtime)

The only problem I ran into is that I couldn't drag the `WebBrowser` control itself as it appears to capture mouse clicks. As a workaround I put the `WebBrowser` in a `Panel`, left a little space at the top so it looks like a title bar, then anchored the `WebBrowser` to fill the rest of the space.

Put the following code somewhere appropriate like Form_Load.

```
Helper.ControlMover.Init(this.TheWebBrowserPanel);
```

You can then drag the `WebBrowser` control by dragging the `Panel` instead:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your solution.But i'm getting an error saying 'The name 'Helper' does not exist in the current context'.. What am I supposed to do? Sorry I'm a beginner.

Comment: Did you look at the link I gave? It has a fully working example to download. I'm just guessing but it sounds like you only copied the one line of code I gave above, or that you've possibly put the code in a different namespace.

Comment: Oh yeah.. i hadn't added that Helper class...!
Thanks a lot!! :)